# Vertical Zoom using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, zooming

Most of the codes on the Internet are horizontal zooming. Hence is there any codes that are available for vertical zooming? I'm using Javascript and HTML for this. As shown in this link, http://codepen.io/katspaugh/pen/GozaaG/, the zooming of the wavefront is horizontal, I want to do it vertically where the top is the + for zoom in, whereas - for the bottom for zoom out. Any recommendations?

```
var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
    container: '#waveform',
    waveColor: 'red',
    progressColor: 'purple'
});...
```